# Limit aggregations to list of values

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I limit aggregations to return only specific list of values? I have something like this:

```
{ "aggs" : {
        "province" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "province"
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
         //my query..
```

But let's say I know list of province for which I want make count ({'province1', 'province2', 'province3'}). Is it possible to restrict returned list of province without influence on my query results?

I want to get:

```
  //list of hits..
  //
  "aggregations": {
        "province": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "province1",
                    "doc_count": 200
                },
                {
                    "key": "province2",
                    "doc_count": 162
                },
                {
                    "key": "province3",
                    "doc_count": 162
                }
                // even if there is more possible provinces
                // I don't want to see them
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use [term filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html?q=terms%20agg#_filtering_values).

Here's an example. Let's say I have visit stats for a bunch of different IP addresses, but I only want to get counts of document for two of them, I could do this:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggregations": {
      "ip": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "ip",
            "size": 10,
            "include": [
               "146.233.189.126",
               "193.33.153.89"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and get back something like:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 7,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "ip": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "146.233.189.126",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "193.33.153.89",
               "doc_count": 3
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to play around with it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/68697646ef7afc9f0375995b6f84181a7ac4cba9

So your example might look like:

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "province": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "province",
            "include": [
               "province1",
               "province2",
               "province3"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch do you use? in elastic 1.3 i get errors when i am trying to pass array to 'include' . (Parse Failure [Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [province]: [include]) Also in doc it says that include take regexp.

Comment: I was using 1.5.1. Probably should have noted that, sorry.

Comment: Great thanks for this post . I was looking for a script to aggs the count for a list of array respectively , with "include " , everything becomes so simple , works on 2.3